# Declaring last row references in Excel formulas through VBA

Tags: vba, excel

In an attempt to take one of my rudimentary programs, and develop it more I am in need of help referencing last row references in Excel formulas as well as dragging formulas down consistently to the last row of a document.

To elaborate I am attempting to reference the last row in an ever expanding mapping table in my vlookup formula. The reason I need this is because as this mapping table expands when I am no longer coding this program, I need my vlookup formula which will be generated every time I run the program to adapt to the ever changing size.

Also my more pressing issue is in regard to taking that vlookup formula and being able to drag it down to the last row of a worksheet. The worksheet will be static and the last row will range anywhere from 70,000 rows to 90,000 rows. I am trying to avoid loops in this scenario as this will already be a very demanding formula and I would hate to loop through each row.

Currently my rudimentary code looks like this (this was built as a proof of concept, I understand the current method isn't the most ingenious but it served its initial purpose).

```
        Ath.Cells(1, x) = "Business"
    Ath.Cells(2, x).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 =  "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[1],Mapping!R2C4:R264C5,2,0),VLOOKUP(LEFT(RC[1],2),Mapping!R1C3:R264C5,3,0))"
    Ath.Range("d2").Copy
    Range("d2:d90000").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Calculate
```

I namely want to change this

```
Ath.Range("d2").Copy
    Range("d2:d90000").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

and

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 =  "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[1],Mapping!R2C4:R264C5,2,0),VLOOKUP(LEFT(RC[1],2),Mapping!R1C3:R264C5,3,0))"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining Dans answer with work of my own I have developed a solution.

```
Sub Formulas()

Dim Map As Worksheet
Dim Ath As Worksheet
Dim last As Long
Set Ath = Sheets("Athena IBT TEST")
Set Map = Sheets("Mapping")


last = Map.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row


ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[1],Mapping!R1C1:R" & last & "C4,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(RC[1],3),Mapping!R1C2:R" & last & "C4,3,0),VLOOKUP(LEFT(RC[1],3),Mapping!R1C3:R" & last & "C4,2,0)))"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps these?

```
Ath.Range("d2").Copy
Range("d2:d" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Paste

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[1],Mapping!R2C4:R" & Sheets("Mapping").Range(ActiveCell.Offset(Rows.Count, -1)).End(xlUp).Row & "C5,2,0),VLOOKUP(LEFT(RC[1],2),Mapping!R1C3:R" & Sheets("Mapping").Range(ActiveCell.Offset(Rows.Count, -1)).End(xlUp).Row & "C5,3,0))"
```

Comment: That formula through an error when implemented. not sure what is quite wrong with it. I'm referring to the second part.